# How to remove non-passive event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, codemirror

I'm developing a code editor. Actually, I'm at the end of the version 2.0.1 which is an important version containing new functionnalities. But just before to update the Google Chrome browser to his latest version (64...), I maked a few change in my code and I don't know anymore what is it.

After Chrome updated, when I open the editor file, I can not click on javascript button or links. This does not work on other browser too. [I took a screen shoot of my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VVXW.png)

There are the events that I used : `click`, `load`, `beforeunload`, `ready`, `keyup`, `keydown`, `online`, `offline`, `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseup`,  `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, and the CodeMirror events.

Can someone help me to remove these non-passive events listener which are blocking events on my app ?

Comment: Aren’t you using any kind of version control?

Comment: i guess the info is not enough to give a solution.

Comment: @Nirus, I really do not know what change I've made to create this issue.

Comment: @lxg I didn't use any version control and I don't use it. I'll think about it next time

Comment: What info can I give to get solution ?

Comment: @José: Do yourself a favour and start using Git (or any other VCS), it’s really easy and a huge help when writing non-trivial software. Let your current situation be a lesson to you. :)

Comment: Thanks @lxg, I started using Git on VS Code

Comment: The console violation messages can sometimes be hints to slowness or bad behavior, but not always. They can sometimes be advices for speeding up the page and fixing them will not fix issues like the one you experience. Did you try to debug the issue regardless of those violations?

Comment: Also, without seeing code and having the option to debug it ourselves, there is little we can do because your question does not provide enough information in order to come up with a reason.

Comment: Ok @PhistucK. I tryed the default VS Code debugger but it doesn't help me anymore. Do you want the source code ?

Comment: @José - why are you not trying the debugger of the Chrome Developer Tools? You are welcome to publish the source code on GitHub if you want, or better yet, a demo URL that reproduces the issue that can be debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a breakpoint on -

```
  $("span.jdb-toggle-fullScreen").click(function(){
```

And it never hit, so I set a breakpoint on the beginning of the containing function -

```
  $(".jdb-author-name").html(jdb.info.detail.author.name[1]).on("click", function() { window.open(jdb.info.detail.author.url); });
```

And it did hit. I stepped over the lines until I got to this code -

```
  // Say Hi Coder every 24h.
  if (jdb.cookie("Hello_World")) { return; }
```

The condition always returns true after you show some message/toast, I assume and when you load the page again anyhow for the next 24 hours, you will never continue running the containing function and you will never get to the code lines that add the event listeners to those buttons.

Solution -

Change -

```
  // Say Hi Coder every 24h.
  if (jdb.cookie("Hello_World")) { return; }
  iziToast.show({
    title: "Bonjour, cher Codeur! ",
    timeout: false, position: "topRight",
    onClosing: function() {
      jdb.cookie("Hello_World", "Yes", {
        expires: 1,
        path: "/"
      });
    }
  });
```

To -

```
  // Say Hi Coder every 24h.
  if (!jdb.cookie("Hello_World")) {
    iziToast.show({
      title: "Bonjour, cher Codeur! ",
      timeout: false, position: "topRight",
      onClosing: function() {
        jdb.cookie("Hello_World", "Yes", {
          expires: 1,
          path: "/"
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

In order not to run only the toast code when the cookie is there.

Comment: Oh yes, to say hello every day, I wanted use `If {} else {}` but I forgot the `else`.
In all ways `if (!jdb.cookie("Hello_World"))` is short and perfect.
I maked change and I can make an event now but I continue to see [Violation] ... for every event in the console.

Comment: I used the Developer Tools, but I guess setting it in Visual Studio Code would have worked just as well (as long as it is connected to Chrome, of course). I never tried it.

Comment: In order to fix the violations, you need to make all of the code (yours as well as the CodeMirror, jQuery and any other third party code) do less while listening to event listeners, as well as change less styles/elements in the DOM and make those operations more targeted.

Comment: So difficult. If that's all there is to it, thank you very much for your help, @PhistucK. I will try to reduce the events and DOM operations as I can.